# Can a Facebook app fetch data from an external server using HTTP requests

Tags: facebook

Want to access data from external service for a facebook application. Not getting a solution on how to do the same.

Comment: You need to provide some code to show what you have tried already.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook apps are `iframe`s inside Facebook. If your application has it's own server-side code, you can access that external service from the server and send the results to the client.

If you don't have your own server-side code, relying on Facebook objects for persistence, than you can access the remote service from the client via JavaScript - but there is a "but". Browsers usually only allow JavaScript to send requests to the domain where the page came from, and obviously your app is not served from the domain of the external service(otherwise it wouldn't be "external"). That means your users will have to set the security options in their browsers to allow access to remote domains - which means you'll have to supply instructions on how to do that, and we all know how good users are at following instructions... Also, having to change security options might scare away some users.

So - if possible, try to do it from your server-side.